# Build regex that separates string of file names with 2 periods

Tags: python, regex

I need to build a regex that, given a string of file names which may contain spaces and between 1 and 2 dots in the file names, returns a list of the file names.

For example:

```
00.37.jpg 00.38.jpg Convert To 3 Channels.xml Deploy All Masks.ini
```

should become:

```
[00.37.jpg, 00.38.jpg, Convert To 3 Channels.xml, Deploy All Masks.ini]
```

I currently have a regex that does this, but only if the file name has *one* period.

Regex = `\ ?(.+?\.\w+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

\ ?(.+?.\w+.?\w+)

Answer (score 2):

You're on a right track, just a slight modification of your regex (adding an optional dot+word group) works fine:

```
\ ?(.+?\.\w+(?:\.?\w+))
```

```
>>> string="00.37.jpg 00.38.jpg Convert To 3 Channels.xml Deploy All Masks.ini"
>>> re.findall(r"\ ?(.+?\.\w+\.?(?:\w+))", string)
['00.37.jpg', '00.38.jpg', 'Convert To 3 Channels.xml', 'Deploy All Masks.ini']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
\w.*?\.\w+(?=\s)
```

Explanation:

- `\w.*?\.`  matches everything until the file extension  dot `.` inclusive
  and
- `.\w+` matches the file extension and
- `(?=\s)` positive look ahead asserts that white space exists ahead of file extension

[demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/fN3eR1/32)

Answer (score 1):

```
string="00.37.jpg 00.38.jpg Convert To 3 Channels.xml Deploy All Masks.ini prog.c the header.h a.b.c.d.e.p"
print re.findall(r"\w.*?\.\w+(?:\.\w+)*", string)
```

**Explanation:**

```
\w          : 1 word character(i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_])
.*?         : 0 or more any character but newline
\.          : a dot
\w+         : 1 or more word character
(?:         : start non capture group
    \.      : a dot
    \w+     : 1 or more word character
)*          : end group, may appear 0 or more times. you can use ? instead of * if you want 2 dot max
```

**Output:**

```
['00.37.jpg', '00.38.jpg', 'Convert To 3 Channels.xml', 'Deploy All Masks.ini', 'prog.c', 'the header.h', 'a.b.c.d.e.p']
```